# React-native not resolved but it is installed

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have got a problem, I tried everything so far and with no success. I have installed react, react-native comes with it, but when I try importing components I get ``
This is Register.js code, I have these imports:

`import React, { Component } from "react";`

`import { View, Text } from "react-native";`

And class:

```
class Register extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
    };

}

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

}

`export default Register;`

I'm trying to use `<View>` and `<Text>`, but I get this error: `Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-native' in 'D:\Darbai\2 kursas 2 semestras\Lankstusis prog. kurimas\Git workspace\team01\research\todosi-react\src\components\user_management'` My guess is it's trying to find react-native in `components\user_management` folder, can this be a problem? Also Here is my files hierarchy.

[image]

Comment: try installing it again with `npm install react-native` without `--save-dev` or `-S`

Comment: It doesn't help, tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out I needed to install all dependencies, it solved my problem. I installed these dependencies with command `npm install <dependency_name>`:
react-scripts,
react-dom,
react-native-web,
react-art,
react-router-native,
react-router-dom